# Swift : Different UIView in each UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I am simply trying to get a different UIView to appear in each cell. So i do this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        print("Index path shold be 0 : \(indexPath.row)")

        maleIcon = MaleIconView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 55))
        maleIcon.center.x = cell.center.x + cell.center.x * 0.5
        maleIcon.center.y = cell.contentView.center.y
        maleIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * maleIcon.bounds.size.width
        cell.addSubview(maleIcon)

    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        //Next UIView(different from one above) will go here
    }


    return cell

}
```

I have a total of 12 cells. The UIView will appear in the correct cell at first, but if you keep scrolling down the same UIView will appear in a different cell, then scroll back up the UIView will be gone and from here it just goes all over the screen. Please please please help! I have to get this app out today!!

Comment: Because `UITableViewCell`s are reused, any `UIViews` that you add to the `UITableViewCell` is also reused (and re-displayed). There are many questions on StackOverflow about this topic. You have two choices: `1)` Create two different tableview cells in the storyboard and select the correct cell type based on the `indexPath` (recommended) or `2)`You need to set or reset anything that ends up getting displayed in the cell; look at the `prepareForReuse` method of the `UITableViewCell` subclass

Answer (score 1):

It's so bad to addSubview in your data source.Because of reuse,views will create many times.The solution is make two type cells with different identifier in your storyboard.And then add the MaleIconView in your storyboard(it will call init(coder:) function,please override that).

Another solution is in your custom cell prepareForReuse(),remove MaleIconView.You don't need to create a new cell for this.

I looked over your codes.You should set gender for your cell in func `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

More elegant solution is use a static table view instead,this will make it easy.

Comment: Hey! So i created a custom class and I feel like it looks pretty good. Would you mind taking a look for me? Could i email you the project? It would help so much! Ive bee trying to solve this issue for 2 days now and cant!

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist I have no time today,you can commit your project to GitHub,I will have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, thank you soo much! Here is the dropbox link to the project. Check out my View Controller, my CustomTableViewCell class, and story board! It all looks good to me, i think its just a small issue! : https://www.dropbox.com/s/023paapwbmi6pd2/Nodule%20Calculator.zip?dl=0

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist femaleIcon,maleIcon and currentIcon,you should remove them before switch.This is because you don't know which kind of cell you will reuse.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is load female icon and male icon in the same cell with its alpha set to 0. then when a user selects the cell and select a button that corresponds with one of the icons, it will set its alpha to 1.0. Does that make sense?

Comment: For sure!! Thank you so much, if you also don't mind, could you edit some of it and send it back to my email: nadalalyafaie@gmail.com    . It would help sooooo much!!!